# Canonical flat C-fields on global ADE-orbifolds

Tags: string-theory

In the context of [M-theory on $G_2$ -manifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-theory+on+G2-manifolds) one considers flat 3-form C-fields on $G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$ -orbifolds, where $G_{\mathrm{ADE}} \hookrightarrow SU(2)$ is a finite subgroup of $SU(2)$, hence a finite subgroup in the ADE-classification. Now for a global ADE-orbifold $X/G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$ there is a canonical flat C-field. Namely:

- flat C-fields are classified by $H^3(X/G_{\mathrm{ADE}}, U(1))$ ,
- there is a canonical map $X/G_{\mathrm{ADE}} \to B G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$ (classifying the $G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$-principal bundle $X \to X/G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$)
- there is a canonical equivalence $H^3_{\mathrm{group}}(G_{\mathrm{ADE}}, U(1)) \simeq H^3(B G_{\mathrm{ADE}}, U(1))$ between the group cohomology of a group and the cohomology of its classifying space;
- there is a canonical cocycle in $H^3_{\mathrm{group}}(G_{\mathrm{ADE}}, \mathbb{Z}/\vert G_{\mathrm{ADE}}\vert) \to H^3_{group}(G_{\mathrm{ADE}}, U(1)) $ which is the restriction of the second Chern-class.

The last statement is due to [Prop. 4.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Platonic+2-group#UniversalPlatonic2GroupIsRestrictionOfString2) in [Epa-Ganter 16](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Platonic+2-group#EpaGanter16) , but even without that precise statement one sees that there should be such a cocycle: Consider the $SU(2)$-Chern-Simons action functional, restrict it to flat fields, and observe that a $G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$-connection necessarily induces (since $G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$ is finite) a flat $SU(2)$-connection. The cocycle in question is the induced Chern-Simons invariant.

Taken together these statements give a canonical flat C-field on any global orbifold $X/G_{\mathrm{ADE}}$ .

My question is if any hints of these canonical flat C-fields on ADE-orbifolds have ever surfaced in the string theory literature?

One might expect this discussed in [Atiyah-Witten 01](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-theory%20on%20G2-manifolds#AtiyahWitten01), but it's not.